# Have to wait to execute jQuery till the service is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am trying to open the hyper links in a new tab. For loading in a new tab I am using the following code, which will run once and adds target="_blank" in the anchor tags:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("ready");
        $("a", "#myCustomContent").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

but the jQuery is executed before the contents is retrieved from the service call and I cannot open the hyperlinks in a new tab, so I tried using the below code:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $("a", "#myCustomContent").each(function() {
       $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
   });
});
```

here it fails as some of the images or the files fails to load, or it will take more time?

I need to find a way to call the jQuery to open the "ahref" tag in a new tab.

Comment: what you mean by service are  you using ajax

Comment: @Optimus, i am storing the contents of the rich text editor in a content management system, and then i am getting the contents using a cmis service and displaying in a new page. here i need to open the hyperlinks in a new tab, <p id="myCustomContent" class="textAlignLeft" ng-bind-html="editorContent | unsafe"></p>.  "editorContent" will have the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. Maybe this will solve the problem

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).parents('#myCustomContent').size() && e.target.tagName=="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(e.target.href);
        }
      })
```

Comment: thanks for the help, the code works fine. i am using the piece of code what Jermey has mentioned. where in he is setting the attribute for anchor tag on click event.

Comment: That is OK. I glad that you found the answer.

Comment: And also take into consideration, sometimes browser may block **pop up** windows.

Comment: i am using the above piece of code, if there is http:// already in the "ahref" it works fine. if http:// is not present then it will open the url in the new tab but it will append the url to the existing url for eg: //localhost:8443/newapp/static/html/www.google.com  how can i add http:// to the hyper link if it is not present using your code

Comment: Lets take that  the current page url is "http: //domen.en/path1". If a tag has `href="/path2"`, then it opens new window with url "http://domen.en/path2". If a tag has `href="path3/path4"` then it opens new window with url "http://domen.en/path1/path3/path4". If you a tag has another url winth another domain then the browser may block the pop up window

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code I'd have a hard time deciphering exactly what the best step would be, but it sounds like you are having images with links load after your code runs. You could always try something that would update the click handler on load:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Or you could look into a function that checks if your images are loaded and sets a timeout until they are all set.

```
var changeTarget = function() {
    if ($('body').find('#img')) {
        //do code it's loaded
    } else {
        //repeat in 100 miliseconds
        setTimeout(changeText,100);
    }
}
changeTarget();
```

Comment: thanks for the piece of code, the first piece of code is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

the below code works fine for opening the hyperlink in a new tab.

if only certain anchor tags(hyperlinks) in the page has to be opened in a new window then the below code can be used

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).parents('#myCustomContent').size() && e.target.tagName=="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(e.target.href);
        }
      });
```

where "myCustomContent" is the id given to the division or the

tag where the hyper link is present.

or

if all the anchor tags in a page has to be opened in a new tab then the below code can be used.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

thanks for the help, @JeremyS and @doniyor